# Count AsyncResponse calls in spring boot metrics

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, micrometer

I have a JAX-RS service backend written in Spring boot 2 and using micrometer for metrics.
By default the metrics contain very nice http metrics as http_server_requests_seconds_count.

These work great for normal GET and PUT requests. One method in my service uses JAX-RS AsyncRequest though.

```
@GET
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("next/{position}")
public void getNext(
        @PathParam("position") Long position,
        @Suspended final AsyncResponse response) throws InterruptedException {
...
// Somewhere in the code in another thread I invoke
response.resume(entity);
... 
}
```

These calls do not seem to be counted at all. Is there a way to enable counting them?
If not should I simply feed the same counters manually from my code?